# Console is able to display all imported XML data but cannot send all information to text file

Tags: c#

I have the following code that gathers all elements and attributes from an XML file and sends to the Console.  This works without issue.

I want to send the data to a text file, but only the first line or last line show up.  Does anyone have any suggestions for having the data sent to a txt file?

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();         

xmlDoc.Load(path);
XmlNode rootNode = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
DisplayNodes(rootNode);
Console.ReadLine();

void DisplayNodes(XmlNode node)
{
    //Print the node type, node name and node value of the node
    if (node.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
    {
         Console.WriteLine(node.Value.TrimStart());    
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(node.Name.TrimStart());
    }

    //Print attributes of the node
    if (node.Attributes != null)
    {                        
        XmlAttributeCollection attrs = node.Attributes;
        foreach (XmlAttribute attr in attrs)
        {
              Console.WriteLine(attr.Name + " " + attr.Value + "\n");
        }
    }

    XmlNodeList children = node.ChildNodes;
    foreach (XmlNode child in children)
    {
          DisplayNodes(child);
    }
}
```

Comment: `I want to send the data to a text file, but only the first line or last line show up` *and where exactly* are you saving this in your code? `xmlDoc.Save(path);`, that's all you need to do...

Comment: I just found the answer to my question.  I used the following:

using (FileStream f = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
using (StreamWriter s = new StreamWriter(f))

For each Console.Writline change to 

s.WriteLine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the static methods in the [`File`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwifxd7XwMPhAhWSqZ4KHYKdBc0QFjAAegQICBAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fdotnet%2Fapi%2Fsystem.io.file&usg=AOvVaw0fvvVCGV5LK0gvtqmN0XZm) class to write to a text file very easily, since it wraps the stream creation for you.

First, we could re-write your method above to return a `List<string>`, which then could be written to the console or a file, or anything else:

```
public static List<string> GetNodeInfo(XmlNode node)
{
    if (node == null) return new List<string>();

    var nodes = new List<string>
    {
        node.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text
            ? node.Value.TrimStart()
            : node.Name.TrimStart()
    };

    if (node.Attributes != null)
    {
        nodes.AddRange(node.Attributes.Cast<XmlAttribute>()
            .Select(attribute => $"{attribute.Name} {attribute.Value}\n"));
    }

    nodes.AddRange(node.ChildNodes.Cast<XmlNode>().SelectMany(GetNodeInfo));

    return nodes;
}
```

Now, we can use this method to get the node information and then write it to whatever we want:

```
List<string> nodeInfo = GetNodeInfo(myNode);

// Write it to the console:
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, nodeInfo));

// Write it to a file:
File.WriteAllLines(myFilePath, nodeInfo);
```

Comment: Thanks Rufus for the reply.  I am still learning about parsing XML.

What does myNode refer to in the following code snippet:

List<string> nodeInfo = GetNodeInfo(myNode);

I assume that this is a starting point from where I want the program to gather the node information from the XML document.  For example, if the starting node is "proHPReportEncounter", would I replace myNode with the starting node?

Comment: It's the `XmlNode` you want to get information from - the input to the method, which would be the same as the input to the `DisplayNodes` method in your question's sample code.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer to my question.  I used the following:

using (FileStream f = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
using (StreamWriter s = new StreamWriter(f))

For each Console.Writline change to

s.WriteLine